# Selecting child element of grandparent in LessCSS

Tags: css, less

As I understand in LessCSS added feature which allows us to select parent element. 
Here is an example of it.

```
.header {
  .menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    .no-borderradius & {
      background-image: url('images/button-background.png');
    }
  }
}
```

The output will be.

```
.header .menu {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.no-borderradius .header .menu {
  background-image: url('images/button-background.png');
}
```

But what if I want to be the output like this. Is it possible or no.

```
.header .no-borderradius .menu {
  background-image: url('images/button-background.png');
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: At present this wouldn't be possible using nesting and parent selectors. You would have to use variables (or) follow Kenavoz's suggestion. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075) which when completed would allow inserting selectors in the middle of a selector chain.

Comment: Thank you Harry for your explanation.